# Change ticket display in Trac

Tags: templates, trac

With default template, trac ticket is available for viewing only, I must click modify to expand properties tab to modify, change state of a ticket.
Now I want to expand that tab automatically? How can I change it quickly without changing the template itself? 
Is it possible to change it with trac.ini file?
I cannot find where's location of default template to change, so I cannot change myself. 
Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same need - even some help with how to change the template would be useful.

Comment: Are you two talking about trac 0.12? IF so, it would probably be good to add that information to the question. I don't have any "Modify" tab in trac 0.11. Actually, I don't have any tabs on the ticket at all...

Comment: yes, I'm using Trac 0.12

Answer (score 8):

I think the best way to enable the behavior you're looking for is to add a custom JS file (which can be injected much like a custom CSS, read TracInterfaceCustomization).

In that file do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#modify").parent().removeClass('collapsed')
 }, 0);
});
```

This code is untested but it should give you the idea. Basically we need to wait until the DOM is ready ($(document).ready) but as there are multiple JS functions called during that event, the setTimeOut sets a slight delay to make sure that the collapse command went through before.

HTH from a professional Trac developer :-)

Comment: I had to use $(document).ready to get this to work, but other than that worked great in trac 0.12. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this numerous times, and couldn't for the life of me get it to work, I even responded to this Question and then deleted it after I realized my false assumption I made. icco's result is the same as mine, change the first line from `$.ready` to `$(document).ready`, AND IT WORKS! YAY! Now to get the TRAC developers to undo this horrible change in the webapp itself. I cannot even fathom the assumption they made in the first place.

Comment: yes, you're right I forgot the $(document).ready, changed that :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using trac 0.12 and had the same issue.

> ...without changing the template itself

I couldn't find a option to configure it but I did notice if you click the "*modify*" quick link at the top right of the ticket then the "Modify Ticket" foldable area is automatically uncollapsed for you.

> I know you didn't ask for it, but just in case, you want a horrible template hack...

Open the template file in editor, e.g. for me in CentOS 5.5:

```
sudo emacs  /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg/trac/ticket/templates/ticket.html
```

Comment out the jQuery line that triggers the *modify* section to collapse on page ready:

```
//$("#modify").parent().toggleClass("collapsed");
```

I found the edit didn't take effect straight away - perhaps the template is cached or something? It worked after a few minutes of shift-refreshing and restarting apache.

**Lets hope someone else answers with a better solution...**

Comment: yes, templates are cached. you need to set
[trac] auto_reload = True in your trac.ini

Comment: But for me, the directory you're talking about /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg is just a file with egg extension?
It's so strange with me, this's first time I use Trac, why your directory becomes my file with same version of Trac?

Comment: Your egg is zipped whereas mine is unzipped. I installed Trac using `easy_install --always-unzip Trac==0.12` because my OS can't recognise zipped eggs. You could unzip your egg using `unzip`, then remove the zipped version (otherwise you'll have two tracs installed).

Answer (score 2):

This is basically Schwarz's answer but in a simpler form

To get ticket contols expanded on load do following. Put following code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">

  <!--! Add site-specific style sheet -->
  <head py:match="head" py:attrs="select('@*')">
    ${select('*|comment()|text()')}
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    // EXPAND TICKET CONROLS ON LOAD.
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#modify").parent().removeClass('collapsed')
     }, 1);
    });
    //-->
    </script>
  </head>

  <body py:match="body" py:attrs="select('@*')">
    ${select('*|text()')}
  </body>
</html>
```

in /path/to/your/trac/project/**templates** directory in file **site.html**.

Comment: I think this way is cleaner.